# Detecting when a html page finishes loading within an object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm loading an html page with an object tag, when the page is fully download, i wanna disp something.

I already tried this but this doesn't work.. :

```
document.querySelector(".obj_excel").onload(function() {
        //Do my thing..
});
```

How can i do it ? thanks you guys

Comment: isn't this: `.onload(function() {` should have to be `.onload = function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".obj_excel").addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert('loded')
})
```

use above piece of code

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload is the function you want to call to when the window and all it's contents have finished loading.

```
 window.onload = function(){
        // do some stuff!
};
```